# Authorize.net Accept SDK will not run to test

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, authorize.net, xcode9

Plugging in the Authorize.net Accept SDK, I am unable to get the project to run.  I used cocoapods to pull the library in.  Any suggestions would be appreciated, I reached out to Developer Support @ Authorize.net last week but have not received a response as of yet:

Here is the error:

```
2017-10-15 09:35:43.555 uploadDSYM[40249:839157] Fabric.framework/run 1.4.1 (160)
2017-10-15 09:35:43.559 uploadDSYM[40249:839157] Launched uploader in validation mode
BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR:     /Users/useruser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unrapp-aiudzaxphrytyggfkouevyvzcbrb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH: ****.app/Frameworks
VALID_ARCHS: i386 x86_64
EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: -
Stripping frameworks
CFBundleSupportedPlatforms for ./AcceptSDK.framework/Info.plist
    Bundle Info: Array {
       iPhoneOS
}
Removing CFBundleSupportedPlatforms from framework plist: ./AcceptSDK.framework/Info.plist
Current architectures for file: ./AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK
Architectures in the fat file: ./AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK are: i386 x86_64 
Stripped ./AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK of architectures:
Code Signing ./AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK with Identity -
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --preserve-   metadata=identifier,entitlements ./AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK
./AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK: replacing existing signature
CFBundleSupportedPlatforms for   ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/Info.plist
Bundle Info: File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/Info.plist
Delete: Entry, ":CFBundleSupportedPlatforms", Does Not Exist
File Doesn't Exist, Will Create:  ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/Info.plist
Removing CFBundleSupportedPlatforms from framework plist: ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/Info.plist
Current architectures for file: ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
Architectures in the fat file: ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib are: armv7 armv7s arm64 
fatal error: lipo: -remove's specified would result in an empty fat file
BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR: /Users/useruser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-aiudzaxphrytyggfkouevyvzcbrb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH: *****.app/Frameworks
VALID_ARCHS: i386 x86_64
EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: -
Stripping frameworks
CFBundleSupportedPlatforms for ./AcceptSDK.framework/Info.plist
Bundle Info: 
Current architectures for file: ./AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK
Architectures in the fat file: ./AcceptSDK.framework/AcceptSDK are: i386 x86_64 
CFBundleSupportedPlatforms for ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/Info.plist
Bundle Info: 
Current architectures for file:   ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
Architectures in the fat file: ./AcceptSDK.framework/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib are: arm64 
fatal error: lipo: -remove's specified would result in an empty fat file
```

**UPDATE:**
OK have been fighting this, and I was able to get the project to build by explicitly stating IOS in the pod file. Now however, once it launches to the phone I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib Referenced from: /Users/useruser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/008A‌​128C-8CDD-4BE5-BC15-‌​3C082CF03B73/data/Co‌​ntainers/Bundle/Appl‌​ication/E8C5A9DE-FDC‌​2-4C3E-A213-44F5842C‌​C9F6/*.app/Framework‌​s/AcceptSDK.framewor‌​k/AcceptSDK 
Reason: no suitable image found. Did find: /Users/useruser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/...‌​/data/Containers/Bun‌​dle/Application/E8C5‌​A9DE-FDC2-4C3E-A213-‌​44F5842CC9F6/*.app/F‌​rameworks/AcceptSDK.‌​framework/Frameworks‌​/libswiftCore.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this (thanks to hiring a gentleman on upwork) was to remove the SDK from the cocoaPod, then turn on the always include swift libraries in the Build Settings.  Re-install the SDK with the cocoa pod and clean the project.  Then magically all worked.